# Oracle OSM - Fulfillment States

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

In Oracle's Order & Service Management application how do we configure the fulfillment state map in order to change the state to "failed" based on the order component failures?

Comment: Sorry, what? How is this related to OpenStreetMap?

Comment: @scai This is about Oracle's Order & Service Management not about OpenStreetMap.